# How to click on a radio button as per the given HTML

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am using a reference, shown below, for the radio button.

```
<input id="checkmo" class="radio" type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'id':getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" name="payment[method]" value="checkmo"/>
```

I have used the below code for this but it failed to click on radio button:

```
WebElement radioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("checkmo"));
radioBtn.click();
```

Comment: did you used the explicit wait before you click the radio button

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If yes, Please share details.

Comment: yep we need to know about the exception for further analysis.

Comment: Try `radioBtn.change();`

Answer (score 1):

The *Radio Button* with which you are trying to interact is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.radio#checkmo"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='radio' and @id='checkmo']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You may introduce the `WebDriverWait` which is **explicit wait in Selenium.**

**Code** :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("checkmo"))).click();
```